# Projector Recommendations?

Tags: projectors

Hi everyone,

I'm looking into getting a projector for my studio so that I can have a big picture to edit and mix to, but I know literally nothing about them so I was wondering if anyone had any recommendations?

My main worry is getting one that doesn't make a lot of noise (as I can't install it in another room) and can have the image size adjusted enough so that I can mount it where I want.

The distance between the back wall where I was hoping to mount the projector and the wall the image would be projected on is 5.3 m (17.4 ft) and it needs to be adjustable so that it projects an image height of no bigger than 84 cm (33 ins), otherwise I'll lose the bottom of the image behind the speakers and computer monitors.

Budget on this would be ideally no more than £500 (currently around $770 / €580), but I have a feeling that may be wishful thinking!

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

with the smallish size room that you seem to have your studio in. have you considered gettng a lcd screen? it's silent, sync (you can check if you need with measurement device) and it's easy to install. most important it's relatively cheaper than beamers/projectors.

Comment: I initially did, but I thought that a projector might be easier and cheaper. I'm quickly discovering that my initial assumption was way off! I'm also worried my walls may not support a big TV, being fabric covered wood frames over insulation filled gaps.

However, I've got in touch with the studio manager to see what he thinks and I'm sure he'll have a better idea of what the walls can take.

I'm naturally cautious about mounting large TVs on walls I'm uncertain of above my speakers and mixer!

Answer (score 0):

Some smaller projectors are pretty quiet though there will be some noise.  Which one depends on lots of factors, but look for what inputs you get and what the lumens are.  I would avoid the cheaper brands, though with a budget of £500 that may be difficult!  Barco, panasonic, chrisite, canon, nec are all good brands and there are plenty more.